# Why does my div move down when I add paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a `<p>` to my`<div class="titleheader">`. So within my div as a child element like this: `<div class="titleheader"><p>generic text </p></div>`.

But when I try to add the `<p>`, my `<div class="titleheader">` doesn't stay at the same position and moves down. Why is this happening?

http://jsbin.com/yitazifivu/1/edit?html,css,output <-- jsbin.

Edit: Adding overflow hidden seems to do the trick (thx kameer), but why is it actually moving down without it..? I'm curious what just happened and trying to learn.

```css
/* css bestand */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container{ 
    background-color: gainsboro;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 950px;
    max-height: 950px;
    margin: auto;
}

.blank1 {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9%;
    height: 9%;
    margin: 10px 30px 60px 65px;
}

.titleheader {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #3B3F40;
    width: 65%;
    height: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
}

.small-a {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14%;
    height: 3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.small-b {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 3%;
}

.main-area {
    display: block;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.straight-a {
    float: left; 
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
    width: 5%;
    height: 20%;
}

.main-area-content {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

.straight-b {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 5%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mert Porfolio</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blank1"></div>
            <div class="titleheader"></div>
            
            <div class="content">
            
            </div>
            
            <div class="small-a"></div>
            <div class="small-b"></div>
            
            <div class="balk-a"></div>
            <div class="content-b"></div>
            
            <div class="main-area">
                <div class="straight-a"></div>
                <div class="main-area-content"></div>
                <div class="straight-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` tag has margins by default. So try resetting them:

```css
p {margin: 0;}
.titleheader {overflow: hidden;}
```

**Working Output: http://jsbin.com/zohapoyivi/1/edit?html,output**

Comment: Hmm.. just tried setting the p {margin: 0;}, the div still moves down when i add the paragraph.

Comment: @Hyrule Use `overflow: hidden` for `.titleheader`.

Comment: hmm.. thanks :-). But now im curious and im trying to understand what just happened.. why did it move down in the first place? And why does overflow solve this?

Comment: @Hyrule The concept is called Margin Collapsing. Search for margin collapse with overflow hidden and you will know. It is a huge concept.

Comment: The behaviour has nothing to do with margin collapsing. An Inline-block element's vertical margins never collapse. This is about vertical-alignment, and the more common solution is to set the vertical alignment of the .titleheader div to `top`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue myself once. It has to do with the `display: inline-block` of `.blank1`.

```
.blank1 {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 9%;
    height: 9%;
    margin: 10px 30px 60px 65px;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of how the display property works. To quickly fix this you need to add to you new `p` tag the property: `display: table;` and you are done.

Comment: Please never ever use `tables` or the ilk for layout purposes. This would work, but this is not the semantic way. :)